# Zend Framework htaccess Rewrite Rule

Tags: php, .htaccess, zend-framework, zend-framework2, wamp

I am using zend application I just re-installed my WAMP for some reason and the existing application which run in my wamp is not running.

I installed WAMP 2.1. My ZEND Folders are as follows

```
 -application
 -design
 -public
    --index.php
    --.htaccess
 -library
    -- Zend
```

And My `.htaccess` has the following

```
Options FollowSymLinks MultiViews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

When I check the file root:

```
http://localhost/project/

 -application
 -design
 -library
    -- Zend
```

I didnt see the public folder in that path, when I remove the .htaccess I can see the folders.

How can I resolve the issue? do I want to add any extension to my wamp? I checked the .Htaccess Its the same as before.

Comment: NB: 'And My .Htaccess has the following' the file name should be lower case, i.e. .htacess (maybe with windows it doesnt matter,but could give you issues, especially if your production server is probably linux)

Comment: Sorry Its my my mistake I just rote in capital letter! :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just click on wamp icon and open apache/httpd.conf and search "rewrite_module". Remove # as below and save it

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

And after restart all service again

might be solve your issue

Comment: Superb! It worked Great! Thanks for your answer.. I dont know still how many thins I need to switch on! for my new wamp :(

Comment: do you have any idea of why the following error comes  Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 3932160) (tried to allocate 393216 bytes)

Comment: try to set the memory_limit option in php.ini to a higher value. see http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php

Comment: My Problem is even my PHPMYADMIN shows the error!! I am using some big DB!!